# Using two sequences for one table in SQL Server 2008 r2 with Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, auto-increment

I´m developing a loan administration application. I have a table/entity named Loan where I save them all. What I need, is to save the invoiced loans with an autoinc (1, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, etc) and to have another autoinc sequence to save all those loans not invoiced (example: 20000, 20001, 20002, etc). The idea is to have both loans in the same table, but with different IDs, then, based on a state, invoiced or not invoiced loan will appear. The application is already in its final stage, so using 2 different tables to save each one of them is not an option. I need advice to find a solution and see if this can be done. By the way, I´m using Entity Framework 4 with C#.

Basically, in a few words, I need to create 2 autoinc sequences for one field of the table. The 2nd autoinc number must start in a high number so as to not be reached by the first one.

Hope somebody can help me out..

**EDIT:**
Guys, I want to elaborate more about the problem because I don´t know if you are getting the point of doing this. The idea of the not invoiced loans is to let the user to give loans "illegaly" without paying taxes for it. Thats why it should be differentiated. I just cant use one id sequence number because if some inspectors looks at the id number would say, "Ok, here we have loans 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, but where is it 4, 5, 6?" The idea of having two sequences one a lot higher than the other, high enought to not be able to reach it by the first, was to achive that. Using the same sequence, but having another field to differenciate if it´s invoiced or not can be a possible solution, but as I have many users, I liked how SQL automatically sets the id of the loan.

Comment: Can you upgrade to SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Or, can you replace your current table with an updatable view, and have the data actually be stored in two database tables? The application wouldn't need to know the difference.

Comment: But I will have two different entities in Entity framework.. I used Postgres for a while, there I can create sequences. Isnt there a way to do that here?

Comment: What happens when you get to 20,000 loans? I think your table design is going to cause a lot of problems in the future and it should be revisted. Maybe have a flag in a different column to show if it is invoiced or not.

Comment: To solve your problem though, you could turn off the autoincrement and isntead calculate in your program what the id should be

Comment: Greg see what I wrote now, I edited. By the way, I could have concurrency issues by calculating it in my program.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg has mentioned, first of all, you will need to turn off auto incrementing on the table. Then create a stored proc that you will call from the data access layer, which will create two records on the table by calculating the correct Ids. This way the data access layer and the business logic will be agnostic to the db-level task.

And as again pointed out by Greg, have a strategy in place to handle the situation when the number of applications reaches 20K mark.

If you don’t mind me asking, why did you select the approach of basing state on a primary/candidate key? Why not maintain a column just to say whether the loan is invoiced or not? Since you are using EF, if you take this approach, you should be able to use Table per Hierarchy to project two sets of data based on the discriminator key (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-4-0-tph-part-2/ and
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Or.. why not query the invoice table, if available (sub query or join) to figure out whether a loan is invoiced.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited the post, please read it, I´m answering some of your questions there.